# Passing data to a selector in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have the following target for a UIButton.

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
```

I also have this method:

```
@objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!, info: String) {
    let btnsendtag:UIButton = sender
    //btnsendtag.isSelected = true
    //let buttonTitle = btnsendtag.titleLabel!.text as! String
    print("BUTTON TAPPED \(info)")

    btnsendtag.isSelected = !btnsendtag.isSelected
    if btnsendtag.isSelected {
        categoryArrayList.append(info)
    } else {
        categoryArrayList = categoryArrayList.filter() { $0 != info }
    }
}
```

how can I send info into this selector?

EDIT:

Reason for need: I have a string, let's just say 'this@that'. However, I want the button to ONLY display the word 'that'. However, when I click on the button, I need to add 'this@that' to the array (like you see in the function).

Thanks

Comment: Where would `info` come from, who would send it?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson i updated the question with the use case, please take a look

Comment: Why can't that hidden part a simple `let part2 = "this@" `? inside the class of that IBAction

Comment: Look at my selector. I have a line commented out. This takes the buttons text. I need to send a string (the buttons text) to my selector... I tried to do a split for the button text, but it doesn't take the right part. Even a substring

Comment: I even tried to make the text of the button hidden and use a textview instead. But then I have a long blank spot.  I tired opacity, which caused that, and then I tried button.title.ishidden and that didn't do anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass a value to a `UIButton`'s selector

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Either access the value from the context of the class **Or** subclass the button and attach the required info with it , then action be like

```
@objc func buttonAction(sender: CustomBt)
```

Comment: if I set the text to a button, but I only want to display part of the text, but I want my selector to get another part, is that possible tat way its set up?

Comment: there is no way to attach that part , the selector function can only notify the sender and event

Comment: Thanks, and the suggested duplicate answer is a great help as well. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50439929/8200290