# how to use parameter inside the selector Tapgesture

Tags: swift

Currently I am making pickerDate to interact with TextField.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var fromDateFilterTextField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var toDateFilterTextField: UITextField!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupUI()

    }
    private func setupUI(){
        fromDateFilterTextField.setInputViewDatePicker(target: self, selector: #selector(tapDone(_:)))
        toDateFilterTextField.setInputViewDatePicker(target: self, selector: #selector(tapDone(_:)))
    }

@objc func tapDone(textField : UITextField) {

}

}
```

```
extension UITextField{
    func setInputViewDatePicker(target : Any , selector : Selector){
        //create a UIDatePicker object and assign to inputView
        let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        let datePicker = UIDatePicker(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: 200))
        datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
        self.inputView = datePicker

        //create a toolbar and assign it to inputAccesoryView
        let toolBar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: screenWidth, height: 44.0))
        toolBar.barTintColor = .red
        datePicker.setValue(UIColor.black, forKeyPath: "textColor")
        datePicker.setValue(false, forKeyPath: "highlightsToday")
        datePicker.backgroundColor = .white

        let flexible = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        let cancel = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: nil, action: #selector(tapCancel))
        cancel.tintColor = .white
        let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: target, action: selector) //7
        barButton.tintColor = .white
        toolBar.setItems([cancel, flexible, barButton], animated: false)
        self.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
    }
    @objc func tapCancel() {
        self.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

I'd like to pass textfield as parameter of tapDone for reuse the code, because I'd like to update the date of differents textfield using only change the parameters of tapDone.

Comment: What is `setInputViewDatePicker`?  Post the rest of your code so that we can make sense of what is being asked.

Comment: Dear friend, my apologies, currently my code as summary only create a picker date, and I'd like to reuse the picker date for update the date of my textfield, so I'd like to send parameter inside the selector.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50439720/how-to-pass-in-parameters-into-objc-function (and many others)

Comment: Ty, for your support, I will check Br.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I understand (generally) what you are trying to do. The short answer is that you can't pass your `UITextField` as an argument for the `Selector` executed by your `UIBarButtonItem`.  That said, there are other options.

The simplest solution I can think of would be to use the `tag` attribute of your `UITextField`s and `UIBarButtonItem`s.  To set this up you would need to update the `tag` of each `UITextField` so that they are all unique.  For example, your `fromDateFilterTextField` could have a `tag` of 0, the `toDateFilterTextField` could be 1.  Just make sure they are all different from each other if you have more.

Once you have updated the tags on your textFields you can make sure the `UIBarButtonItem` has the same tag by modifying your `setInputViewDatePicker` method like so:

```
func setInputViewDatePicker(target : Any , selector : Selector){
    ...
    let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: target, action: selector) //7
    barButton.tintColor = .white
    //Make the barButton tag match the associated textField's tag
    barButton.tag = self.tag
    ...
}
```

Even though you can't pass the `UITextField` as an argument, you *can* pass the `UIBarButton` executing the `Selector` by changing your selector method like this:

```
@objc func tapDone(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

}
```

Then you can determine which textField is associated with the `tapDone` by looking for that matching tag:

```
@objc func tapDone(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
  switch sender.tag {
  case 0:
    print("This is fromDateFilterTextField")
  case 1:
    print("This is toDateFilterTextField")
  default:
    print("This is a different textField")
  }
}
```

You can also look into `viewWithTag` in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622429-viewwithtag) for possible improvements, though sometimes being really explicit makes your code more readable and less prone to bugs.